# AWS Cloudwatch alarm watching ECS containers state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

Let's say that I have ECS cluster with 10 containers running.

I want to have Cloudwatch Alarm which trigger SNS toppic **IF** 5 of the containers changed there state in 5 minutes.

What good approach can I use for this?

Answer (score -1):

You could create a CloudWatch event rule to trigger on any state change of container. This rule then triggers a Lambda which will put metric data into CloudWatch for a custom metric (i.e. state change). Then create a CloudWatch Alarm to monitor this custom metric and trigger SNS as alarm action based on your condition.

Comment: Ok, but you didn't said what metric to monitor to detect when the state of a container has changed. I'm trying to find which one to use ...

Comment: You'll have to create a custom metric - there's no current metric which will say that state has changed for container. That's why the CloudWatch event rule is required to listen to container/task state change events. That should be used to create your required custom metric.